# Webdriver io, file upload using input type=“file”

Tags: javascript, input, coffeescript, webdriver-io

I am writing tests on **CoffeeScript** using **Webdriver.io** and **mocha**. The code is processed using the CoffeeScript compiler.

In the process, I needed to upload a file to the server using the *input type = "file"* (*display: none*) element.

I try to transfer the file address as follows (of course, first making it visible: *style.display = 'block'*):

```
elem_input = $('div.class_1 input.class_2')
browser.elementSendKeys(elem_input.elementId, '/home/user/ ... /test.txt')
```

The file cannot be found, the error message "**File not found**" appears in the console.

I carefully checked the path, it is correct. If you upload the file directly through the interface, manually, there are no problems either.

What could be the reason for this situation and what could be the solutions to the problem?

Comment: Here you can find how to properly set path to a file: https://webdriver.io/blog/2019/06/25/file-upload.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file_path = browser.uploadFile(FILE_PATH)
# Путь к загружаемому файлу на устройстве
$('div.my_selector').setValue(file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, For Me setValue() showed error :**element not interactable**
And addValue() Worked.

```
const filepath = path.join(process.cwd(),'path/to/file');
const input = await $("//input[@type='file']")
const remoteFilePath  =  await browser.uploadFile(filepath)
await input.addValue(remoteFilePath)
```